# Select that takes the available space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code :

```css
[class*="col"] {
 background-color: lightblue;
 border: 1px dotted black;
}
.game {
    height: 80%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}
.menu {
 height: 90%;
    margin: 10 10 0 10;
}
#main {
     display:block;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
.s {
 height: 32px;
 width: 32px;
 background-color: azure;
 position: absolute;
}
.lfouk {
 height: 10%;
}
.hgt { 
 height: 100%;
}
form {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 

<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    
     <div class="col-xs-4 lfouk"></div>
     
     <div class="col-xs-1 lfouk"></div>
     <form class="col-xs-1 lfouk">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="select" class="col-lg-12 control-label text-center">Largeur</label>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <select  class="form-control" >
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </form>
     <form class="col-xs-1 lfouk">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="select" class="col-lg-12 control-label text-center">Hauteur</label>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <select  class="form-control" >
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </form>
     <form class="col-xs-1 lfouk">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="select" class="col-lg-12 control-label text-center">Départ</label>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <select  class="form-control" >
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <select  class="form-control" >
                <option>1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </form>
     <div class="col-xs-1 lfouk">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="select" class="col-lg-12 control-label text-center">Arrivée :</label>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <select  class="form-control" >
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <select  class="form-control" >
                <option>1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
                <option>Option 3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-xs-3 lfouk">
      <div class="col-xs-6 lfouk"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 lfouk"></div>
     </div>
    
   </div>
  </div>
```

soo executed on the browser, the "départ" & "arrivée" selects selected options are not visible due to the small size
is there a way to make the select take more space ? It works perfecly but still it may be visually more beautiful

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change your bootstrap classes.

```
<form class="col-xs-1 lfouk">
```

As you can see you use col-xs-1 this uses only a twelfth of the screen so maybe try to use col-xs-2 or even 3